# How to change the length and color of lost message in msc package?

Tags: floats, msc

I use lost message in msc diagram. I need to control the length and color of the lost message line as shown below. I looked at the manual, it suggests using `\selfmesswidth` in the msc definition. I tried it but it made no effect at all. Here is a sample script:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{msc} 
    \usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[b!] 
\vspace{-1cm}
\[
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\centering
\setmsckeyword{} 
\drawframe{no} 
\hspace{-1cm}

\begin{msc}[small values, /msc/level height=0.6cm, /msc/label distance=0.5ex , /msc/first level height=0.6cm, /msc/last level height=0.6cm, /msc/top head dist=0, /msc/bottom foot dist=0]{}
\setlength{\instwidth}{2.5\mscunit} 
\setlength{\instdist}{5\mscunit} 

\declinst{A}{}{A}
\declinst{B}{}{B}

\mess {Message1} {A}{B}
\nextlevel
\lost[side=left]{}{}{B}

\nextlevel
\mess {Messag2} {A}{B}
\nextlevel

\end{msc}
} 
 \]
 \caption[caption]{Figure} 
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I need to change the length and color of the lost message as shown below. I could not find a way to do that in the manual.
[image]

**EDIT:** The document class updated. You also need the msc.sty from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/msc?lang=en)

Comment: Your example is not working for me. First it has a strange non-standard document class (which I have not), second: replacing it with a standard `article` class, it gives me some errors. Please make it working for all of us in order for us to be able to help you

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code, and have you looked at the log file? According to the documentation you cannot use `[small values, /msc/level height=0.6cm, /msc/label distance=0.5ex , /msc/first level height=0.6cm, /msc/last level height=0.6cm, /msc/top head dist=0, /msc/bottom foot dist=0]` as an option. It throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following command to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\lostredlong[1][l]%
  {\psset{linecolor=red}% color lines in red. Unfortunately this affects all lines.
   \selfmesswidth=\instwidth% set the length of the arrow
   \def\lostfound@position{#1}%
   \def\lostfound@type{lost}%
   \def\msc@circlefillstyle{red}% fill the circle in red
   \lostfound@B%
  }
\makeatother
```

Setting `linecolor` and `\selfmesswidth` affects also all of the following commands. To avoid this, enclose the `\lostredlong` invocation in braces.

```
{\lostredlong{}{}{B}}
```

It is basically possible to add these braces to the definition of the command `\lostredlong`, but this requires to copy much more code from `msc.sty` should probably be avoided.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{msc} 
    \usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\lostredlong[1][l]%
  {\psset{linecolor=red}%
   \selfmesswidth=\instwidth
   \def\lostfound@position{#1}%
   \def\lostfound@type{lost}%
   \def\msc@circlefillstyle{red}%
   \lostfound@B%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{}
\setlength{\instwidth}{2.5\mscunit} 
\setlength{\instdist}{5\mscunit} 

\declinst{A}{}{A}
\declinst{B}{}{B}

\mess {Message1} {A}{B}
\nextlevel
{\lostredlong{}{}{B}}

\nextlevel
\mess {Messag2} {A}{B}
\nextlevel

\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to compile your code. I got: `Error: Undefined control sequence` that points to the line that contains: `{\lostredlong{}{}{B}}`.

Comment: @user6875880 Which error message exactly? Which undefined control sequence? My guess is that you LaTeX distribution is outdated.